# HTTP Status 500 with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Checked the other posts didn't help.
This is  in Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.6.0. When I start the server, the web page opens up. After I enter a word and click on submit I get A status 500 error.

[Screen shot JARS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXoF9.png)

[Directory Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwLA1.png)

Hellocontroller.java

```
  package controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.*;

//import com.sun.javafx.collections.MappingChange.Map;

public class Hellocontroller implements Controller {

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {

           String name = req.getParameter("name");

           Map m = new HashMap();
           m.put("msg", "Hello ...."+name);                             

           ModelAndView mav =new ModelAndView("success",m);

        return mav;
    }

}
```

HelloWorld-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />


    <bean name="/hello.ds" class="controller.Hellocontroller">
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.InternalViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.ds</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
<h1>HelloWorld</h1>

<form action ="./hello.ds">

NAME:<input type = "text" name="name">

SUBMIT<input type = "submit" value="sayHello">


</form
```

success.jsp

```
${msg}
```

HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

---

```
type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve
```

Comment: print your pom.xml!!

Comment: I dont know how to use maven.so this project was created without a pom.xml.

Comment: ok than, the list of dependencies you have used

Comment: @Paja Dependencies you mean Jar Files ? If yes, i will upload the screen shot of it.

Comment: What is the spring version?? i mean jars

Comment: com.springsource.org.apache.commons.fileupload-1.2.0.jar,com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient-3.1.0.jar,com.springsource.org.codehaus.jackson.mapper-1.0.0.jar,org.springframework.oxm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar,org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar,org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A,org.springframework.web.struts-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar,org.springframework.web-3.0.1.RELEASE-A

Comment: @paja and sam  I have given a link of the picture in sts and also manually written it down in the above comment

Comment: @sam I have given a link of the screen shot with jars.

Comment: Oh and there is a commons-logging.jar as well.

Comment: To everyone I updated the HelloController.java with import statements and also there is a link to the screenshot of my JARS and Directory

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing web.xml to like below...add load on start up

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.ds</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Im getting a status 400 when I did load on start up

Comment: WEB-INF/lib should contain jars..and check in buildpath whether all the jars are referenced correctly or not

Comment: Do... Properties -> deployment assembly->add->java build path entries

Comment: Please have a look at the screen shot of my Jars in the link I posted above.I did the properties thing, it did not work

Comment: where you added your jars...lib folder is empty??

Comment: Add to webcontent/web-inf/lib folder and the add to build path

Comment: now I am getting HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet HelloWorld threw exception

Comment: So now it is working fine...now tell me What is the exception??

Comment: Yes. when I was doing a Right click>build path somehow the jars were not  landing in the lib folder. I had to manually copy the jars from my system and paste it into the the lib folder.

Comment: Now I am getting the below error, should I close this question and open up a new question or continue?.....  HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet HelloWorld threw exception

Comment: Asked new question?

Comment: ya i can help..close this question(accept answer)..add new question link in comment